# How to call a pool with sleep between executions within a multiprocessing process in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

In the main function, I am calling a process to run imp_workload() method parallely for each DP_WORKLOAD

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import multiprocessing
import subprocess

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for DP_WORKLOAD in DP_WORKLOAD_NAME:
         p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=imp_workload, args=(DP_WORKLOAD, DP_DURATION_SECONDS, DP_CONCURRENCY, ))
         p1.start()
```

However, inside this imp_workload() method, I need the import_command_run() method to run a number of processes (the number is equivalent to variable DP_CONCURRENCY) but with the sleep of 60 seconds before new execution.
This is the sample code I have written.

```
def imp_workload(DP_WORKLOAD, DP_DURATION_SECONDS, DP_CONCURRENCY):
     while DP_DURATION_SECONDS > 0:
           pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = DP_CONCURRENCY)

           for j in range(DP_CONCURRENCY):
                pool.apply_async(import_command_run, args=(DP_WORKLOAD, dp_workload_cmd, j,)
                # Sleep for 1 minute
                time.sleep(60)

           pool.close()

           # Clean the schemas after import is completed
           clean_schema(DP_WORKLOAD)

           # Sleep for 1 minute
           time.sleep(60)
```

```
def import_command_run(DP_WORKLOAD):
    abccmd = 'impdp admin/DP_PDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD@DP_PDB_FULL_NAME SCHEMAS=ABC'
    defcmd = 'impdp admin/DP_PDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD@DP_PDB_FULL_NAME SCHEMAS=DEF'
    
    # any of the above commands
    run_imp_cmd(eval(dp_workload_cmd))

def run_imp_cmd(cmd):
    output = subprocess.Popen([cmd], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    stdout,stderr = output.communicate()
    return stdout
```

When I tried running it in this format, I got the following error:

```
    time.sleep(60)
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, how can I kickoff the 'abccmd' job for DP_CONCURRENCY times parallely with a sleep of 1 min between each job and also each of these pool running in multiProcess?

Working on Python 2.7.5 (Due to restrictions, can't use Python 3.x so, will appreciate answers specific to Python 2.x)

P.S. This is a very large script and complex file so I have tried posting only relevant excerpts. Please ask for more details if necessary (or if it is not clear from this much)

Comment: Is that python version-specific (v2.7)?

Comment: Yes @ack Can't switch to Python 3.x

Comment: Syntax error is in the line above `time.sleep()` - missing `)` - **complete** traceback helps analyzing problems :)

Comment: You seem to be needlessly creating the pool over and over in your `while DP_DURATION_SECONDS > 0:` loop rather than creating it once prior to the loop (perhaps with a different pool size). And in this loop you are submitting to the pool multiple tasks without explicitly waiting for their completion. Do you *expect* these tasks to complete before starting the next iteration? Do you *want* these tasks to complete before starting the next iteration?

Comment: @Booboo I want DP_CONCURRENCY number of tasks to be running at a time. So, if 4 tasks have completed I want the next 4 to kick in with a sleep of 1 min.

Comment: The code is still not clear. The formal parameters to `import_command_run` do not match how it is being invoked with `apply_async` and `imp_workload` will loop forever (which may be as intended). Anyway, by having pool creation in your loop and not explicitly waiting for completion of submitted tasks, if imports take longer than 60 seconds, you will have multiple pools running concurrently with the number of imports running concurrently continuing to rise. (more ...)

Comment: But if you move the pool creation outside the loop and get rid of `pool.close()`, then you will never have more than DP_CONCURRENCY tasks running. But if your imports take longer than 60 seconds to complete, you are submitting tasks more quickly than they can complete and they will just queue up and the number of tasks queued up to run that will never run will continue to grow to infinity -- and that's not right either. Because you have oversimplified your `import_command_run` function and have never explained what these functions are trying to do, it's really impossible to suggest something.

Comment: You need to describe in English what you are trying to accomplish. For instance: "I have 10 imports I need to do over and over at most 4 at a time but the time between doing the *same* import must be at least 60 seconds." This, of course, may not be anything like your actual requirements, but rather an example of what I think you need to specify. Another note: you are passed `DP_DURATION_SECONDS` but you never decrement this in your loop but meant to. So maybe in your description, perhaps instead of "over and over" it should be "repeat for DP_DURATION_SECONDS".

Comment: Your description "So, how can I kickoff the 'abccmd' job for DP_CONCURRENCY times parallely with a sleep of 1 min between each job and also each of these pool running in multiProcess?" does not really correspond to your code at all. As I mentioned, you cannot just submit jobs every minute without the possibility of the number of parallel jobs growing *or* the number of queued up jobs growing *if* the job takes longer than one minute to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Let me offer two possibilities:

**Possibility 1**

Here is an example of how you would kick off a worker function in parallel with `DP_CURRENCY == 4` possible arguments, `0`, `1`, `2` and `3`, cycling over and over for up to `DP_DURATION_SECONDS` seconds with a pool size of `DP_CURRENCY` and as soon as a job completes restarting the job but guaranteeing that at least `TIME_BETWEEN_SUBMITS == 60` seconds has elapsed between successive restarts.

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
from queue import SimpleQueue

TIME_BETWEEN_SUBMITS = 60

def worker(i):
    print(i, 'started at', time.time())
    time.sleep(40)
    print(i, 'ended at', time.time())
    return i # the argument

def main():
    q = SimpleQueue()

    def callback(result):
        # every time a job finishes, put result (the argument) on the queue
        q.put(result)

    DP_CURRENCY = 4
    DP_DURATION_SECONDS = TIME_BETWEEN_SUBMITS * 10
    pool = Pool(DP_CURRENCY)
    t = time.time()
    expiration = t + DP_DURATION_SECONDS
    # kick off initial tasks:
    start_times = [None] * DP_CURRENCY
    for i in range(DP_CURRENCY):
        pool.apply_async(worker, args=(i,), callback=callback)
        start_times[i] = time.time()
    while True:
        i = q.get() # wait for a job to complete
        t = time.time()
        if t >= expiration:
            break
        time_to_wait = TIME_BETWEEN_SUBMITS - (t - start_times[i])
        if time_to_wait > 0:
            time.sleep(time_to_wait)
        pool.apply_async(worker, args=(i,), callback=callback)
        start_times[i] = time.time()
    # wait for all jobs to complete:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

# required by Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Possibility 2**

This is closer to what you had in that `DP_DURATION_SECONDS == 60` seconds of sleeping is done between successive submission of *any* two jobs. But to me this doesn't make as much sense. If, for example, the worker function only took 50 seconds to complete, you would not be doing *any* parallel processing at all. In fact, each job would need to take at least 180 (i.e. `(DP_CURRENCY - 1) * TIME_BETWEEN_SUBMITS`) seconds to complete in order to have all 4 processes in the pool busy running jobs at the same time.

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
from queue import SimpleQueue

TIME_BETWEEN_SUBMITS = 60

def worker(i):
    print(i, 'started at', time.time())
    # A task must take at least 180 seconds to run to have 4 tasks running in parallel if
    # you wait 60 seconds between starting each successive task:
    # take 182 seconds to run
    time.sleep(3 * TIME_BETWEEN_SUBMITS + 2)
    print(i, 'ended at', time.time())
    return i # the argument

def main():
    q = SimpleQueue()

    def callback(result):
        # every time a job finishes, put result (the argument) on the queue
        q.put(result)

    # at most 4 tasks at a time but only if worker takes at least 3 * TIME_BETWEEN_SUBMITS
    DP_CURRENCY = 4
    DP_DURATION_SECONDS = TIME_BETWEEN_SUBMITS * 10
    pool = Pool(DP_CURRENCY)
    t = time.time()
    expiration = t + DP_DURATION_SECONDS
    # kick off initial tasks:
    for i in range(DP_CURRENCY):
        if i != 0:
            time.sleep(TIME_BETWEEN_SUBMITS)
        pool.apply_async(worker, args=(i,), callback=callback)
    time_last_job_submitted = time.time()
    while True:
        i = q.get() # wait for a job to complete
        t = time.time()
        if t >= expiration:
            break
        time_to_wait = TIME_BETWEEN_SUBMITS - (t - time_last_job_submitted)
        if time_to_wait > 0:
            time.sleep(time_to_wait)
        pool.apply_async(worker, args=(i,), callback=callback)
        time_last_job_submitted = time.time()
    # wait for all jobs to complete:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

# required by Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```